# Formula for calculating a cell value based on variable percentage bands with specific threshold levels

Tags: google-sheets

I have a [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IL_2BqchnAEU0Jm4VYplCaDL0vWzl9sW2vt8lovKUpQ/edit?usp=sharing) with two tabs - one containing percentage "bands" values and the other with data in a table which includes rows for new entries and columns off to the right edge which store running totals depending on the entry type. The running totals depend on the row entry being of the same type and month period. This all works as expected.

I need to calculate a value in column `I` based on a row entry amount/cell (column `H`) which references the running total for that entry type `AA:AF` and month and then uses the relevant predefined percentage "bands" values (tab R1).

I had successfully got this working when a single entry would only ever cross *one* "band" level (the bands were previously tens of thousands apart) by using SWITCH and VLOOKUP functions.

The current formulas in column `I` use this method which no longer works since the percentage bands are now much closer together than they were before and a single entry could take the running total value for that entry over multiple bands (and not just the previous band, as before).

On the example sheet, cell `H6` contains 9,900 as a test value since this increases the running total for that row `AB6` to 16,313 from the prior running total for that type, 6,413 and spans 4 percentage bands:

Band A: 0-7,500 - 5%

Band B: 7,500-10,000 - 7.5%

Band C: 10,000-15,000 - 15%

Band D: 15,000 - 25,0000 - 17.5%

My original formula first checks the entry Type using a SWITCH, then matches the highest "band" value using a VLOOKUP and then an IF to check if the previous running total was less than the highest matched "band" value, calculating and adding the difference if needed.

I've tried to figure out how to calculate the same result when multiple bands are crossed (as in example) but I can't find a way to structure the formula so that it can apply universally down the column using the matched band rate(s), previous running total and new running total values.

Is there a mathematical way to do this or will this require multiple nested IF statements etc or would another approach work better?

Comment: would you be willing to change the structure/layout of the "bands" sheet to make it more conducive to a formula?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by modifying the formulas on [this page](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/pricing.htm). Changing the layout of the bands was a good first move.

Now, column `I` calculates the value from the current running total (matched from type in column `A`) and subtracts the value calculated in the same way but using the previous running total to give the amount applicable to the newly entered value on the same row in column H. I've some more testing to do but fairly sure it works correctly. Any other ideas, feel free to suggest!

Provisionally working sheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e2pdyOi7dz_ZA8zfNtsHxieEUb5fiZGpD_FwRvkHyYw/edit?usp=sharing